# A word for being introduced to a concept so obvious you feel like you should have known it years ago

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm currently writing a scene where a character (the story is told from someone else's perspective so I can't explore how they feel) is introduced to a concept that seems obvious in retrospect, and they're stumped that they didn't think of it before.

There are words like "feeling sheepish" and "felt like a numpty", but they don't convey the right feeling. Ideally the word would convey curiosity; the character realizing the possibilities the concept introduces, and would be somewhat "posh" or "scholarly".

Answer (score 1):

**aha moment**

> a moment of sudden realization, inspiration, insight, recognition, or comprehension

*The *aha moment* you experience when you've been trying to remember the name of a song and three hours later it hits you…*

*—Jeffrey Kluger*

[NOTE: Aha is sometimes followed by an exclamation point and is also often placed in quotation marks.]

[*Merriam-Webster*]

Answer (score 0):

You could say that the character had been "blind(ed) by/to the obvious"; [this article in Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/daviddisalvo/2013/09/28/study-experts-can-be-blinded-to-the-obvious-just-like-the-rest-of-us/?sh=649d8e1a48e9) provides an example of the phrase, meaning to be unaware of something that seems obvious in retrospect.